# How to set test group to @Test methods dynamically using TestNG?

Tags: java, testing, testng

I want to set group to a particular @Test method at runtime depending on some condition

Suppose I have the following classes

```
public class MyTest1{
  @Test
  public void test1(){
    System.out.println("test1 called");
  }
}

public class MyTest2{
  @Test(groups={"group1"})
  public void test2(){
    System.out.println("test2 called");
  }

  @Test(groups={"group2"})
  public void test3(){
    System.out.println("test3 called");
  }
}
```

Now while running test I am sending "-groups group1" or "-groups group2" to TestNG in command line. So testng is running either test2() or test3() depending on the group name passed. Now my requirement is to run test1() that is not supposed have any groups attached. Whatever group I provide to testng runner this test1() should be run every time. I tried with implementing alter method of IAlterSuiteListener but I could not get all the test methods including which are not considered to run. So I could not set the group name at runtime.

So is there any other way to set groups to @Test methods (having no groups defined) at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perhaps start exploring the beanshell way of method selection that TestNG provides to you for this purpose.

Sometime back I wrote up a blog post which talks about how to work with Beanshell expressions in TestNG. You can read more about it [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/beanshell-and-testng/) and refer to the official TestNG documentation [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell).

Quoting the TestNG documentation,

> TestNG defines the following variables for your convenience:
>
> - java.lang.reflect.Method method:  the current test method.
> - org.testng.ITestNGMethod testngMethod:  the current test method.
> - java.util.Map groups:  a map of the groups the current test method belongs to.

So with just your example, I went ahead to create a suite xml file that looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="1265_Suite" parallel="false" verbose="2">
    <test name="92" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                    <![CDATA[whatGroup = System.getProperty("groupToRun");
                (groups.containsKey(whatGroup) || testngMethod.getGroups().length ==0);
                ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.MyTest1"/>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.MyTest2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And I run it via the command prompt using maven as below : (The test classes are basically what you shared in your question )

```
mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=dynamic_groups.xml -DgroupToRun=group2

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
...
... TestNG 6.11 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

test1 called
test3 called
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 15.377 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: I have one question here. Will it work if I provide -DgroupToRun=group1,group2?

Comment: What do you mean its not working for you ? Can you please help elaborate what exactly is NOT working for you ?

Comment: And no it wont work if you try to specify multiple groups because the beanshell that I shared in my answer deals with only 1 group. You would need to enhance it to support multiple groups.

Comment: may be I need to enhance it.. Thanks

Comment: If my response has answered your question, can you pls help accept my response as an answer ?

Comment: I tried different ways for including more than two groups in your example. Nothing seems to work. Can you help me in this?

Comment: Can you show me what you have tried ? We can take it up from there. You can post your code on gist.github.com and share a link.
Here's what I would do: 1. Get the group name as a JVM arg. 2. Split the group name by commas and have them stored in an array. 3. Loop through the array and apply the contains() condition for every element. 4. Break the loop and set flag as false even if one of the conditions() check returns false.
5. Use the flag obtained in 4 to do a "OR" operation with "testngMethod.getGroups().length==0" condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the logic. I made a slight change. Instead of returning false when a containsKey() check fails, I returned true if at least one check passes. That way if I provide two groups out of which one is invalid, then the other valid group will still run along with the test method that has no group defined.

Comment: <![CDATA[String [] runGroups = System.getProperty("groups").split(",");
                boolean flag = false;
                for(String group : runGroups)
                    if(groups.containsKey(group))
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                (flag || testngMethod.getGroups().length ==0);
                ]]>

Comment: Here i ran into another problem. If someone provides a regex as -DgroupToRun="group.*" like -groups works with testng runner parameter, it will not work.

Comment: I have solved pretty much everything with this beanshell. Recently I have found another problem. With the beanshell that I have written is able to run groups having regex as well as normal groups, but if the selected method is dependent on another method, then it is giving an exception.

Comment: If I am using 
`(groups.containsKey("smoke") && groups.containsKey("sanity"));` to select two groups , I am getting `no test to run` on console . Selecting one group works fine. How can I select two groups? I am not supplying `DgroupToRun`  param from command line. I just want to select both groups in `testng.xml`

Comment: @user1207289 I think you need to use OR, not AND.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of doing this if you are specifying groups.  However, there are two other ways of doing this.

1. You can mark all your tests with no groups in a group called "nogroups" and include that group while you run
   Or
2. If you have huge number of tests that you already have, then write up an Annotation Transformer which basically adds cases with no groups in this group --sample example below.  Writing a transformer can help you control edge cases programmatically as well.

`public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    if (annotation.getGroups().length == 0) {
        annotation.setGroups(new String[]{"noGroups"});
    }
}`

Comment: In this case, I will have to specify noGroups to testng runner. Then the same problem comes. I can just attach noGroups with the test method itself instead of using transformer.

Comment: That was the first option i gave you. In either case you will need to specify noGroups in xml or in runner